# react-router-dom this.match.params.id being undefined while using render

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios, react-router-dom

I am currently trying to use Axios to retrieve information about an arrangement to display on the page, but seem to be having problems with the url of where it get's the information from.

I am having this issue with react where I simply want to get the id from the url using ${this.match.params.id}.

I tried this line of code where I add props to the lambda expression and putting it in as an object. That was one suggestion  from someone erlse but did not work.

```
<Route path="/arrangement/:id" render={(props) => ( <ArrangementPage
sponsors={this.state.sponsors} {props} /> )} />
```

App.js

```
<Route path="/arrangement/:id" render={() => ( <ArrangementPage sponsors={this.state.sponsors} /> )} />
```

ArrangementPage.js

```
  componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get(`/wp-json/wp/v2/arrangements/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
    .then( res => this.setState(
      {
        arrangement: res.data,
        isLoaded: true
      }
    ))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

Axios.get(`/wp-json/wp/v2/arrangements/${this.props.match.params.id}`) returns an error message that implifies that this.props.match.params.id is undefined.

Comment: in the router try spreading the props to make it available render={(props) => ( <ArrangementPage
sponsors={this.state.sponsors} {...props} /> )} /> I guess it will work fine.

Comment: Ahh just the three dots! Alright thank you very much it works like a charm